# libgmp-10.dll missing when trying to compile gnu objective c under windows

Tags: objective-c, c, gcc

I installed GNUStep http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html but when compiling helloworld.m I got libgmp-10.dll missing.

What should I do to make it work ? (I'm on Windows 7 64 bits)

I have already made it work a few months ago though I think I was on Vista 32 bits then.

Update: found here

https://rb.freedroid.org/r/1101/diff/?expand=1

```
166 
    Nota:, if an error window opens complaining about libgmp-10.dll missing, then you used a bugged version of the MinGW installer
167 
    (some DLLs are not correctly installed). To fix the problem, just type the following commands:
168 
     cp /mingw/bin/libgmp-10.dll /mingw/libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2
169 
     cp /mingw/bin/libmpc-2.dll /mingw/libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2
170 
     cp /mingw/bin/libmpfr-1.dll /mingw/libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2
171 
     cp /mingw/bin/libiconv-2.dll /mingw/mingw32/bin
172 
     cp /mingw/bin/libintl-8.dll /mingw/mingw32/bin
```

But I only found libgmp-3.dll in /mingw/bin/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The DLL isn't missing; it can be found in the MinGW-`bin` directory. On my system:

```
D:\Opt\MinGW32.11.11\bin\libgmp-10.dll
```

The problme can easily be fixed by adding the MinGW-`bin` directory to the `PATH`:

```
set path=%path%;D:\Opt\MinGW32.11.11\bin
```

Now the compiler works fine.

Comment: Why do you have to do that instead of using `-Idir` ?

Comment: @Pred, You don't *have to* include the directory in the `PATH`, the compiler switch should also work. There might be cases where you'd have to edit a Makefile, or several Makefiles, or pass the option on the command line, or in an environment variable. Adding the MinGW directory to the `PATH` might just come in handy. YMMV.

Comment: I figured out that when I put the existing path at the end, I would get errors when creating directories, or deleting directories and binaries. The OS would use the built-in tools, and I would get a permissions error. So I put the MinGW paths at the front of the path, and then I was able to use all the functionality required. I do run into some weirdness creating directories and such. This might be unique to Windows 8.1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded `mingw-get-inst-20110802` and I got the same error as you.

I found the required DLL files in the specified directory though.  Applying the specified solution has solved my problem.

I may suggest you to try to redownload and reinstall the MinGW..